# Unity - Rotating image on button made button un-useable

Tags: unity, 2d

I recently started trying to teach myself Unity2D development using some tutorials and something weird was happening last night while I was working on my project.

Basically I have an image that serves as a dialog window. On this image (as a child object) I added a button to essentially act as "next" button for paging through NPC dialog. I set the button to use an image of an arrow poiting to the right. This worked great, got the click method hooked up with no issues. The weirdness happenened when I added a second button.

I duplicated the first button and then, since I wanted it to be a previous button, just did a 180 degree rotation on the Y axis of the button to have it be reversed. When I did this though the button did not work at all. It acted as if it was disabled (click event never fired even though code was there). Ultimately, after fiddling with it for 30 minutes I decided the cause was because I had flipped the button on the Y axis (undoing this rotation caused it to work like I expected).

So my question is: **Why did doing that rotation cause the button to be un-useable?**

*Note: I dont care about how to fix it to make it work, Ive decided to get rid of that button all together. Im really only interested in the mechanics behind unity that would cause the button to not work after being flipped. Also, if someone can point me to relevant links on the matter that would be great. My googling did not return anything useful however Im not sure I really googled it correctly.*

Comment: @DMGregory, while I see the duplicate is asking the same question, it appears that the OP wants a solution. I dont want a solution, I want to know why Unity does this. Also the answer to that question gives a how to fix type of answer rather than a this is the reason that happens kind of answer.

Comment: The question of why is asked in that question too, and there's some speculation about it in the comments. Ultimately though, only the Unity dev team can tell you why they chose to implement it this way, so a better way to answer that is to ask them directly.